# Android Zoom and Crop

Tags: android

I need to crop a picture. What I want to do is crop it by zooming the picture and then saving whatever is visible on the screen. Can anyone help me?

Comment: i am using the TouchImageView class file to zoom.

Comment: So you can zoom, what have you done to try and crop?  How are you keeping track of the actual coordinates of the box, that is on the image?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Image Crop library.

https://github.com/naver/android-imagecropview

please try this :)

Comment: Old question, but I highly approve of this library.